# Why does popper.js doesnt work in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, popper.js

i already tried a lot of option that can be found on the internet but i can't get it to work..

I ran in the terminal:

```
npm install popper.js --save
```

next i editted my "resources/js/bootstrap.js";

```
 window._ = require('lodash');      
 import Popper from 'popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js';
 /**
 * We'll load jQuery and the Bootstrap jQuery plugin which provides support
 * for JavaScript based Bootstrap features such as modals and tabs. This
 * code may be modified to fit the specific needs of your application.
 */

try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    window.Popper = Popper;
    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}
```

then i added this to my webpack.mix.js

```
mix.autoload({
jquery: ['$', 'window.jQuery',"jQuery","window.$","jquery","window.jquery"],
'popper.js': ['Popper']
})
```

i then added this code to my include template that contains my header

```
 <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer>

 $(function () {
 $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
 })
 </script>
```

and this to my page

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Click to toggle popover</button>
```

then i ran

```
npm run dev
```

This is my package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "popper.js": "^1.14.4",
        "vue": "^2.5.7"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "popper": "^1.0.1",
        "tooltip.js": "^1.3.0"
    }
```

I'm kind of a newbie when it comes to javascript, but i'm interested in learning

please tell me what i am missing

Thanks in advance

include file (header)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer>
  $(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
    </script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet" 
type="text/css">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
        @include('inc.navbar')
        <div class="container">
        @include('inc.messages')
        @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
    <!--<script src="/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script src="/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $('textarea').ckeditor();
    </script>-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried using CDN?

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`
You should place this before the bootstrap script.

Comment: i tried but still nothing, `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous">
    $(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
    </script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>`

Comment: do you want it only for bootstrap? Because I use the CDN links from here: 
`http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/download/`
And don't forget both jquery and popper need to be above the bootstrap link and before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: ill edit my question so you can see my whole setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two closing `body` tags. Then you are loading the scripts in the header. 
When you use `src` in the script it will load the file, it will not use the body. So you should use:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer />

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
    });
</script>
```

But put this at the end of your `body` content, just before the `</body>` tag.

-- EDIT --

Using CDN links

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: nope, still not working.. and you are right my mistake, by trying to much i didnt see the double `</body>`

Comment: so I am not sure it compiles right for you. Just by what you have passed I don't see the errors. So again if it is just for the bootstrap try to use the CDN links is what I will suggest. And use them in the right order. First jQuery then Popper than Bootstrap.

Comment: And if i put the code in like you stated i get a `$ is not defined` error in my chrome developer console

Comment: if you look at my resources/js/bootstrap.js you will see that the loading order is correct, and it is bootstrap in combination with laravel, and the CDN links dont work for me as i tried multiple times, i guess i'm just missing something crucial

Comment: now i only need to figure out how to include these files so that i can use them locally, but verry much thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post, but this confused me on a few different occasions and I ended up here looking for the answer, before I found it elsewhere. I am by no means an expert, but for me, it was the 'defer' in this line:

`<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer>`

The 'defer' causes the scripts to load *after* the page loads, which is also after you load your popper scripts. jQuery is loaded in your js/app.js, so it's not loading until after your popper scripts, even though js/app.js is located above them on the page.

You can remove the 'defer' from that line, which will cause it to load right away and before your popper scripts, but that broke some other things for me (things that were looking for elements in the body that hadn't yet loaded). So I added the 'defer' to my other `<script>` lines as well, which caused them to load in the right order. Hopefully this might work for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

edit `package.json` add .js

```
"dependencies": {
    "popper.js": "^1.0.1",
    "tooltip.js": "^1.3.0"
}
```

and don't ever use `popper.js` or `popper.min.js` as CDN or script tag on head or body, case
it will conflict with app.js script tag

Answer (score 0):

Just add before closing body tag `</body>`

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer />
```